# How to change a relation between entities manually in Spring Boot JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

I need to change the relationship between two entities manually (OneToOne to OneToMany), but when I try to change the relationship in the respective entitie classes, when I try to run the project always throws thos exception, anyone knows what to do to make it works? [image]

Comment: Please don't use a picture for an error because we can see only what you want to show and we can't scroll to see if something happened before. Use text. Please edit your question with more details about what you mean by "changing the relationship manually". Did you edit the entity classes, the JDL? Did you create a Liquibase migration?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post pictures of code, or pictures of error messages, or pictures of logs, or generally pictures of any kind of text. Text in pictures cannot be searched, text in pictures cannot be copypasted into an IDE, text in pictures cannot be copypasted into a web search engine, and text in pictures cannot be read by blind or otherwise visually impaired people. Just copy the text and paste it into your question as text. If you are unsure how to format it properly, don't worry, we can help with that.

Comment: How can I copy the exception output here?